# Vue render function causes maximum call stack

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So I am migrating application from vue 2 to vue 3 and now I am getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. This is happening inside this template:

```
 <div>
     <comp-form :errors="form.$e" @submit="onSubmit">
       content
     </comp-form>
 <div>
```

And I have this `<comp-form>` component which uses `render()` function.

```
  render() {
      return (
        <form>
          {this.$slots.default}
        </form>
      );
    }
```

I managed to make error fix by changing `render()` function to `<template>` layout:

```
<template>
  <form>
    <slot/>
  </form>
</template>
```

And this doesnt cause the error. But I want to keep `render()` function but I dont understand why it doesn't work with `render` but works with `template` layout.. Would appreciate some help. :)

Comment: This is how you use render functions in Vue: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html (without JSX)

Comment: Well I have included jsx to babel config ```"@vue/babel-preset-jsx"``` but it seems doesnt work. Maybe it is because of this new babel plugin I added ```"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is how](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpNUMtuhDAM/BUrF0BikzuiK1X9jVwoGwor8lBstpUQ/14nYbV783jG9ox38RmCfGxGdKLHMS6BAA1t4ardYoOPBF/eBpiit1BJlUCSV9r1quhZyYCMDetAhhFAP7IsV5pG71fA1VMm1Mn06m1AtKLcutghyDt6x272PH4SqEUHuZN6fD9hLWaigJ1SOI3J1B2ljz+KKxk3R4s10qC9fEf/iybyYi3SikO7g08+o7ySvzLvMMNxhi5ptTN/mbqZadhWlnCP8qvqEH3AlodSTISj4bKEj8xHB3UDH1eY6+q2PKq2yOS5qG6ap6m3n4rjH0Ebjbs=) to achieve a render function in Vue:

`App.vue`

```html
<script setup>
import Comp from './Comp.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <comp>
    cool slot
  </comp>
</template>
```

`Comp.vue`

```html
<script>
import { h } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup(props, { slots }) { 
    return () => h('form', slots.default())
  }
}
</script>
```

---

Here is [the doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html) if you want more details (+ the approach for JSX).

Comment: Yea with default it works. But just cant find out whats wrong when JSX syntax is used