# Element gets rendered not corretly from render() function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So I am migrating to vue 3 from vue 2. And I have this `render()` function:

```js
render() {
 return (
  <form class={['form', this.horizontal ? 'form--horizontal' : 'form--vertical']} 
        onSubmit={this.submit}>
    {this.$slots.default}
  </form>
 )
}
```

And well when webpack is compiled and I open app console I see this render like this:
[image]

Well I have no idea why is this happening? Any suggestions what could cause this?

Comment: What should I return ?

Comment: By looking here https://blog.logrocket.com/using-jsx-with-vue/ it seems it should return `()` and cant find anything else what I should return.

Comment: This question is quite close to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74234579/8816585 I'm 80% to mark it as a duplicate but I'd rather keep it open for now, depending on how you improve it + effort you put in it.

Comment: The question lacks clear problem statement. What exactly is incorrect?

Comment: why `onSubmit={this.submit}` is rendered as `attrs=[object Object]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the answer vue 2 had this babel plugin as JSX support `"@vue/babel-preset-jsx"` well on vue 3 it is this `"@vue/babel-plugin-jsx"`